# collect rows that have the same foreign key mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
ID|FK|cost|name  |
--|--|----|------
1 | 1| 200| name2|
2 | 1| 100| name2|
3 | 3| 900| name1|
4 | 2| 500| name3|
5 | 2| 100| name3|
6 | 2| 200| name3|
```

---

i need this result Where

```
ID|FK|cost-|name  |
--|--|-----|------
1 | 1| 300 | name2|
2 | 3| 900 | name1|
3 | 2| 800 | name3|
```

Comment: i need cood mysql

Comment: Then this is wrong place. No one will write code for you here.

Comment: How can I get an answer quickly ؟؟؟

Comment: By visiting some site with freelancers.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL should work to get the desired output

```
SELECT id, fk, SUM(cost) AS cost, name FROM <table> GROUP BY name ORDER BY id;
```

Going forward, please read the SO guidelines and help center to understand the purpose of this forum.